# Regularity check of languages

Tags: automata

[image]

L1 will not be CFL also as it needs more than one stack to count. L1/L2  gives concatenation and the result will  be $a^{n} b^{2n} c^{4n}$ which is again non regular. Am I right? I am little bit confused for L1/L2 case as for some y, xy belongs to L1.

Help appreciated :)

Comment: I think you don't understand the $/$ operation. It is not concatenation and $L_1/L_2$ is not what you said.

Comment: @MJD can you please clarify a bit further what exactly it is !!!

Comment: Here are some examples: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871662/finding-right-quotient-of-languages/

Comment: @MJD thanks a lot for that answer :) But can you explain the given question's answer.. I think L1/L2 still not regular because L1/L2 will contain L1 for epsilon case(where n=0). i am confused .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that $L_1$ is not even context-free, though the reason that you give is not a proof; it’s not too hard to find a proof using the pumping lemma for context-free languages, however, and it’s even easier to prove that $L_1$ is not regular using the pumping lemma for regular languages.

It’s true that $L_1\subseteq L_1/L_2$, for the reason that you gave in your second comment: $\epsilon\in L_2$, so for each $x\in L_1$ we can set $y=\epsilon\in L_2$ and have $xy\in L_1$, which implies that $x\in L_1/L_2$. That’s not enough to show that $L_1/L_2$ is not regular, however: after all, $L_1\subseteq\Sigma^*$, and $\Sigma^*$ is certainly regular. To decide whether $L_1/L_2$ is regular, we must see what else is in $L_1/L_2$.

Suppose that $xb^nc^{2n}\in L_1$. If $n=0$, then $x\in L_1$, and if $n>0$, then $x$ must be $a^n$. This shows that

$$L_1/L_2=L_1\cup\{a^n:n\ge 0\}\;.$$

To finish the problem, you can use the pumping lemma for regular languages to show that this is not regular.

Comment: M.Scott  exactly what needed..thanks a ton :) I was thinking like that but you made it super clear :)

Comment: @ViX28: You’re very welcome; glad it helped.